# Powershell - Remote connection to a non-domain joined Windows server (add-computer and get-wmiobject ) isn't working

Tags: windows, powershell, uac, winrm, windows-server-2022

So I'm working on a script to deploy and config servers automatically by Powershell for Windows Server 2K22. Unfortunately, when I'm trying to do an add-computer or an get-wmiObject, I have this error;

Get-WmiObject : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
or
add-computer : Cannot establish the WMI connection to the computer 'x.x.x.x' with the following error
message: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

test-wsman -ComputerName x.x.x.x -Authentication Default -Credential (get-credential)

Access denied.

So I'm not able to add a brand new server to my domain remotely by PowerShell in my environment.

I tried couple some solutions, but none of them worked. I may miss something in my configs, so I'll post everything here;

- Winrm service is enable and I kept the basic config (winrm quickconfig)
- Enable-psremoting
- Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) is allow through Windows Defender Firewall
- I enable some Firewall rules;
  Windows Defender Firewall Remote Management (RPC)
  Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)
  Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)
  Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)
- I disabled UAC in regedit
  HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin - 0
  HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ConsentPromptBehaviorUser - 3
  HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy - 1

HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA - 0

My account have full access to AD, so I can create AD objects in every OU. It worked before on Windows server 2K19, so my guess is that a deep config in Windows may block me.

** In Win2K19, I didn't do winrm configs, I just kept the basic config when I activated it and it was working fine.

Also, I looked so much in Microsoft 's website and other ressources, so don't answer me to look at the documentation, I already did :). Maybe I didn't understand something inside though, so I'm open to any suggestions!

Thanks a lot, much appreciated!